# Apache Camel Generic Router - pass exchange properties to static class methods

Tags: apache-camel

I am trying to create a generic router whose processor and other attributes are populated from a static class. Here is sample code.

```
public class GenericRouter  extends RouteBuilder( {
     @Override 
     public void configure() throws Exception {
         from("direct:generic-route")
         .process(Util.getProcesss(“${exchangeProperty[processKey]"))
         .ToD(Util.getUrl(“${exchangeProperty[urlKey]"));
     }
}

Public class Util{
    Map<String,Object> routerResources;
    static {
     //load routerResources
    }

    public static Processor getProcessor(String processorKey){
       return (Processor)routerResources.get(processorKey);
    }
    public static Processor getUrl(String urlKey){
       return (String)routerResources.get(urlKey);
    }

 }
```

The generic router is expected to post a rest call. the properties "urlKey" and "processorUrl" are already available in exchange. I finding it difficult to pass exchange properties to static Util class methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access properties of an exchange in plain java you can use `.process` or `.exchange`. If you need to access body or headers you can use `e.getMessage().getBody()` and `e.getMessage().getHeader()`

```java
from("direct:generic-route")
    .process( e -> {
        String processKey = e.getProperty("processKey", String.class);
        Processor processor = Util.getProcessor(processKey);
        processor.process(e);
    })
    .setProperty("targetURL").exchange( e -> {
        String urlKey = e.getProperty("urlKey", String.class);
        return Util.getUrl(urlKey);
    })
    .toD("${exchangeProperty.targetURL}");
```

Also make sure you fix the return type of this method:

```java
public static Processor getUrl(String urlKey){
    return (String)routerResources.get(urlKey);
}
```

As a side note, you can actually use map stored in body, header or property through simple language.

```java
public class ExampleTest extends CamelTestSupport {
    
    @Test
    public void example(){

        template.sendBodyAndHeader("direct:example", null, "urlKey", "urlA");
    }

    @Override
    protected RoutesBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
        return new RouteBuilder() {

            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
             
                Map<String, String> urlMap = new HashMap<>();
                urlMap.put("urlA", "direct:pointA");
                urlMap.put("urlB", "direct:pointB");

                from("direct:example")
                    .setProperty("urlMap").constant(urlMap)
                    .log("url: ${exchangeProperty.urlMap['${headers.urlKey}']}");
            }
        };
    }
}
```